# Lenovo Legion Y720-15IKB SSD replacement

Tags: ssd, m.2

Hi I currently own the Lenovo Legion Y720-15IKB, which has a 1TB hard drive and a 128GB SSD. I want to replace my current SSD with a Samsung M.2 960 EVO 500GB SSD. I understand how to actually replace the actual parts. If my OS is saved on my current SSD, how would I transfer it to the new SSD? Also, is there anything that I need to do in the boot menu upon start up?

Comment: Are you removing old drive to use the new M.2 960 EVO  drive as boot drive?

Answer (score -1):

You can use Norton Ghost to make clone of your SSD. If you use anu linux you can use dd.

Comment: Could you explain the steps Taz would have to go through? How he'd connect a second drive to his computer to do this copy? While this software may be the correct software for the job, it is far from being the complete answer.

Comment: This doesn't answer the author's question